# Can I limit the runtime of a cronjob

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I've got a cronjob which runs hourly that is occasionally taking too long to run, is there any way I can set a maximum runtime and the job gets killed if it exceeds that?

This is on an Ubuntu 10.04 server.

Thanks, jebw

Answer (score 11):

Try the `timeout` command.  For example:

```
0 * * * * timeout -2 3540 /path/to/your_command.sh
```

will send a SIGINT to your command if it hasn't completed in 59 minutes.

Comment: Good info. You missed '-s', but it is "timeout -s 2 3540 <command>".

Comment: The one installed via apt on ubuntu uses the syntax I mentioned: `usage: timeout [-signal] time command...`

Comment: What does 'dpkg -S bin/timeout' gives? In fact mine is from coreutils and is pure GNUish.

Comment: `timeout: /usr/bin/timeout`

Comment: 10.04, same as the OP.

Comment: Yes, in 10.04 it is there but gone in 10.10.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. The way we do it is to make a script with a lock file and have the script check for that lock file before start running again, so it can check if it is already running and decide if it runs, if it waits for the other to end or if it kills the other before running.

A lock file is just a empty file or a file with the other script `PID` saved somewhere like `/var/run` or `/var/lock`.

Answer (score 0):

cakemox's answer is the best. Otherwise, just put the pid intoa  file or use killall on anouther cronjob a minute earlier to kill the process.